# Do I need to repeat a preposition?

Tags: prepositions

> - Tigers are found both in Asia and in Africa.
> - Tigers are found both in Asia and Africa.

I could use *in* twice in this sentence. Can I omit it the second time?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.  If the objects (Africa and Asia) of the prepositions can use the *same* preposition (in), you may use the preposition once and combine the objects for simplicity.  You may, but you are not required to.

To my ear, it sounds better to move the "both" in the combined case, though:

Tigers are found both in Asia and in Africa.

Tigers are found in both Asia and Africa.

Comment: But my book goes with the first sentence. That's why I am confused.

Comment: Both sentences are correct - is your book saying that only the first is correct?

Comment: Yeah..my book says " Tigers are both found in Asia and in Africa'' is correct